# Forward the "maindomain" but keep e.g."maindomain/en/" still functional

Tags: .htaccess

I have a domain "example.com" with old content and cms. This domain "example.com" needs to be forwarded to a new domain with new content, new cms and new server. At the same time the url e.g. "example.com/en/" or "example.com/it/" still should point to the old content and cms. I wonder if this is possible at all? I couldn't find any solution so far!

Answer (score 0):

Check this 1:1 rewrites (example.com/link -> new-domain.com/link), excluding /en/* and /it/*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(\/en/\|\/it\/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

or all to new-domain.com (example.com/link -> new-domain.com), excluded /en/* and /it/*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(\/en/\|\/it\/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-domain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the solutions. I took the second one. Unluckily ist does not work. 
"example.com" is beeing forwarded to the new domain but "example.com/it/" is also beeing forwarded.